# How to turn on (back) Fiddler to show HTTP protocol errors?

Tags: fiddler

Few hours ago I turned off showing HTTP protocol errors by checking the checkbox (Do not show) in the modal error dialog. Now I am do not find where to turn on.

I must be missing something, but I've reviewed all the Options dialog tabs, still not found...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you navigate to `Tools -> Fiddler Options -> General`, change the value in `If protocol violations are observed` to something other than `Do nothing`.